# Select random from listbox and correlated item in second listbox

Tags: c#, button, random, textbox, listbox

I have two sets of items in two listboxes. `listBox1` has items listed out like:

```
red
yellow
blue
```

and `listBox2` has items like:

```
1
2
3
```

There are many more than three items per listbox. I also have two textboxes, `textBox1` and `textBox2`. I have been successful in having a random item from `listBox1` show up in `textBox1`, and I am now trying to check, with a button, if the text in `textBox2`, manually entered by the user, matched the corresponding items in `listbox2`.

So far, I have:

```
Random random = new Random();
int a; int n;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    n = listBox1.Items.Count;
    a = random.Next(n);
    textBox1.Text = listBox1.Items[a].ToString();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //unsure
}
```

I am trying to have `button2` check for whether or not `textBox2` has typed into it the correctly corresponding item in `listBox2` and display a message of some sort if it is correct. I'm a beginner at this, but I think I adequately grasp how to if/else the message if I can get the code leading up to it correct.

How do I check for such a link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it is a WPF application and you populated the list box with strings then you can get the Text property value of the text box and the Items property value of the list box. The Items property will returns an ItemCollection and you can use the Contains method like so: listBox2.Items.Contains(textBox2.Text) to return true or false.

Similar approach would work for a WinForms application also, just that the classes from the .NET framework that you use will be different, for example the list box Items property in this case returns a ListBox.ObjectCollection. Both of these libraries provide the relevant Text, Items and Contains properties/methods.

In both cases the MessageBox.Show() method can be used to display the appropriate method.

Comment: Your answer comes very close to what I'm looking for. The problem I'm still running into is if `textBox1` has the second item from `listBox1` randomly placed into its text, `button2` should only return true if the user has entered exactly into `textBox2` what the second item is in `listBox2`. Is this method able to do that?

Comment: The ItemCollection can be accessed like so: items[index] as well.So you can get the index value from listBox1 which is a in your case and do something like so: listBox2.Items[a].Equals(textBox2.Text).

Comment: Perfect! I was wondering how to use [a] to identify both items. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to compare them with the if statement

```
if (thing1 == thing2) {
    //do things
}
```

So we know thing1 is the currently selected item in the listbox2, and thing2 is the text of textbox2.

You can grab the text in both of them via text

```
if (textbox2.Text == listbox2.Text) {
   //do stuff
}
```

If you want to check if the entered text is in any of the options, you'll want to use .contains

```
if (listbox2.items.contains(textbox2.Text) {
   //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Does this if-statement go within `button2_Click`? I'm receiving a "Non-invocable member 'TextBox.Text' cannot be used like a method." error. Also, when `textBox1` receives its randomly selected text from `listBox1`, how will `button2` know to check the exact corresponding number of `listBox2` if that hasn't yet been selected?

Comment: Sorry, I think its just Text not Text(). That error means you are trying to use a property (which won't have a () on it) like a method (which does have a () because you can maybe pass parameters into it.)